# Integral operation on a SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose I have an SDE, for example

$dN=rdt + adB$

for constants a and r, as in Oksendal chapter $5$. He take the "integral" of this and ends up with,

$N=rt + aB$.

without regard or mentioning what is going on. Sure integration is inverse of differentiation. But these objects above are not the same differentiation. The first being a Riemann or Lebesgue and the second an Ito integral. So how does one make sense of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbolic expression $dN=r\,dt+a\,dB$ is defined to correspond to the integral equation
$$
N_t-N_0=\int_0^tr\,ds+\int_0^ta\,dB_s
$$
which in the case of constant coefficients can directly be integrated in the Riemann resp. Ito sense.

In short, your question is not.

Comment: So the integral that he takes(which is an operation in my opinion) is just a definition?

Comment: It is all on page 62 in his book. Just google "oksendal sde" and you find the pdf

Comment: In my version it is not on that page and I do not find your example. He discusses the geometric Brownian motion $\frac{dN}{N}=r\,dt+a\,dB$ where you need the Ito formula for the logarithm to proceed on the left side.

Comment: He does what I describe above as far as I understand. The N in the denominator dont matter.

Comment: After 5.1.3 he says or...hence... . Thats the part that messes things up for me.

Comment: Do you note the factors $N$ on the right side in $dN=rN\,dt+aN\,dB$? This is defined as the integral equation $N_t=N_0+r\int_0^tN_s\,ds+a\int_0^tN_s\,dB_s$. Most of the theory before is concerned with confirming that you can indeed manipulate the differential expression algebraically in the indicated way. Informally, $$d\ln N_t=\ln N_{t+dt}-\ln N_t=\ln(1+\frac{dN_t}{N_t})=\frac{dN_t}{N_t}-\frac12\frac{(dN_t)^2}{N_t^2}+O(dt^{3/2}).$$ From the quadratic term, only the term with $(dB_t)^2\sim dt$ is large enough to contribute to the integral.

Comment: Yes, that is per definition and using the constant coefficients.

Comment: No, that would still be equal, but you can not compute the integrals on the right that easily, especially the second one.